# How do you correct 2 unrelated msi having the same UpgradeCode

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm a bit light on detail but I think we have a problem.

Using the copy/paste method of boostrapping an installer project in wix, it appears we seem to have missed updating the UpgradeCode to ensure they are unique...

```
<Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="SOME-BAD-FOO">
```

So, it is my understanding that this is "not good" (r)(tm)

At the moment the users of the 2 installers with this issue are unlikely to have installed both, but they may in future.

Looking for ideas on how to fix this issue before it becomes an installed nightmare... 
Maybe Windows cannot even install both at the same time?
Is there some way to perform an upgrade install/patch and change the UpgradeCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, it is my understanding that this is "not good" (r)(tm)

That is really not good, you should be careful to not do that in the future as it can give you, and your users, a lot of headaches.

However, the solution is very simple. All you need to do is to change the upgrade code for one of the packages, and to add the current upgrade code in the [Upgrade table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the new version, so it removes it, if it is found on the machine.

If you are sure the second version will be installed by all your users that have installed the first one, in the next release you should remove the upgrade code the from Upgrade table, to make sure you don't have any conflicts with the second package, i.e. the still using the first upgrade code.

Comment: Am I reading this wrong?  How would this prevent an ambigious accidental uninstall of the wrong product?

Comment: @Christopher I only answered on the subject of changing the upgrade code in the next version, without expanding the discussion in this direction, which of course is a very good question. However, this can be easily handled with a launch condition that checks for the product code of the other product, which I assumed Greg already knows.

Comment: I guess my point is the solution isn't really simple.  An expanded discussion (difficult here, agreed) would include all the servicing scenarios that could have issues and how to best mitigate.   Hopefully these products will never meet and hopefully they have different version number ranges as this can be a real mess to untangle.

Answer (score 2):

One question I'd ask would be are you using Major or Minor Upgrades.

If Minor, I've never tried changing the UpgradeCode but not the ProductCode.  I think it would be OK but I'm afraid to find out.

If Major Upgrades, do the products use different version number ranges?  1.0-1.9 , 2.0-2.9?  If so, it would possible to change the UpgradeCode in both installers ( just leave the 'dirty' guid in your past )  and then use the old guid in your UpgradeTable  with a version # as a the key to identifying the correct product codes.

If not, do you know every single ProductCode that was ever released to the wild for both products?  A custom action could be used to query MSI for installed ProductCodes and then compare it to a list of known guids to decide whether it applies or not.

You'll have to leave the code in forever though.  Old versions of software have a tendency to stick around forever.

Comment: This would be done as a major upgrade, though we are also using minor upgrades.  It is a good point on checking version ranges and luckily we are not overlapping so can use it as a differentiator.